# How to play with pocket 10 in low stack situation?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, cash-game

How to play with pocket 10's in low stack situation?

[image]

Comment: A: Call 1.00$                                                
                                          B: Raise 3.00$ 
                                                                                       C: All in 
                                                                                                                          D: Fold

Comment: C all day every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a cash game, you should reload. If its a tournament, all-in is likely the best play.

Its probably better for this particular hand if you raise to somewhere between $2-3 since its a premium hand and you want people to call, but the more premium hands you put in a raising range, the less premium hands you have that will shove. This makes it easier to call your shove when you have a marginal hand like KJs.

Shoving is probably the better overall play.

Comment: If hero shoves and everyone folds he increases his stack by 18.75%. That's a good outcome. If he goes all in and gets 1-2 callers, he's in a very favorable situation. Min opening off this stack depth is really just asking for trouble. The chances of someone passing up on a 8bb shove in a regular cash-game are very slim anyway. If you think you can get action anyway, just shove.